# Cygwin linking shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cygwin, shared-libraries

---

**UPDATE:**

Removed old question about .so files. They aren't intended to work on Windows.

I solved the below using a header file. I am guessing it is a standard convention to use .h file every time you link using C++?

mydll.h:

```
#ifndef mydll_h_
#define mydll_h_
void hello();
#endif
```

myprog.cc:

```
#include "mydll.h"
int main ()
{
  hello ();
  return 0;
}
```

mydll.cc:

```
#include <iostream>

void hello()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

---

Alternatively, I tried .dll library using Cygwin with this guide: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html

The compilation for their .c files work, but I am trying to get it to work for my .cc files. Any ideas?

mydll.cc:

```
#include <iostream>

void hello()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

myprog.cc:

```
int main ()
{
  hello ();
  return 0;
}
```

I typed:

```
g++ -c mydll.cc
g++ -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o
```

But when I type:

```
g++ -o myprog myprog.cc -L./ -lmydll
```

I get:

```
myprog.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
myprog.cc:4:10: error: ‘hello’ was not declared in this scope
   hello ();
```

Comment: "'hello’ was not declared in this scope" this has nothing to do with libraries. .cc is a C++ source code file suffix. You need to declare functions in C++.

Comment: On windows, there are no "shared libraries". There are DLLs. The default filename suffix for them is .dll. Cygwin is not changing that.

Comment: I tried changing functions but it gives the same error. Onto your second comment, I guess that narrows down the problem to the second one.

Comment: "I tried changing functions" No idea what that means. If you want to ask a question about a compilation problem, ask a question and provide source code. If you tried several variants, post all of them.

Comment: The gcc compilation tutorial for cygwin works only for .c files. How do I configure it to work for .cc files?

Comment: You need to learn C++ first. Your program is not legal C++. No amount of configuring gcc will help you compile it, you need to correct your code.

Comment: Is it because I need a header file to be included in the driver program? I am confused. I am not familiar with c and assumed some of the syntax might carry over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121802/discussion-between-dobob-and-n-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing a compiler problem; not a linker problem. The compiler is telling you that when it compiles myprog.cc, it can't find function `hello()`.

You need to write a function declaration for `hello()`. Note: you're function *definition* for `hello()` is in mydll.cc.

A function declaration would simply be:

```
void hello();
```

(1) You could place this one line of code in your `myprog.cc` **above** `int main()`.

(2) You could also place this one line of code in a header file that is included *at least* by `myprog.cc` and optionally by `mydll.cc`. But good programming practice dictates that the header file should be included by both.

If you follow option 1, the following version of `myprog.cc` will fix your compiler error:

```
void hello(); // "extern void hello();" would be more proper.

int main ()
{
  hello ();
  return 0;
}
```

Option 2 would entail:

`myprog.cc`:

```
#include <mydll.h>

int main ()
{
  hello ();
  return 0;
}
```

Either way results in successful compilation and execution:

```
>g++ -c mydll.cc
>g++ -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o 
>g++ -o myprog myprog.cc -L./ -lmydll
>./myprog.exe
Hello World!
>
```